# Можно ли вообще не ставить капчу?

Tags: веб-программирование, php, javascript

Здравствуйте, я вот думаю: можно ли вообще не ставить капчу? Если формы как таковой нету, а есть просто пачка инпутов в структурированных дивах, так же и сабмит это просто див без inline события. Весь сбор, валидация, отправка с js пост жисоном на php

Comment: Не ставьте - капча та еще гадость. Только адрес сайта скажите - люблю писать спам-ботов.

Comment: Весь сбор, валидация, отправка с js пост жисоном на php

Кто такой "жисон"?

Comment: @xEdelweiss, просто у ребят весь сайт работает на js, отключишь js - ни одна кнопка работать не будет. Я просто обобщил свой ответ, дополнив его таким образом. "Допотопные браузеры" - фтопку! Я теперь всегда ставлю проверку - если ie 7 - пустой черный экран с кукишем. )))

Comment: Это спасет от спам-ботов, но не спасет от пользователя, решившего лично **вам** засрать сайт. Выбор за вами.

Comment: А еще можно не мыть руки, не пользоваться презервативами, не пристегиваться в машине и в самолете и переходить улицу на красный свет. Что еще можно, можно почитать у Остера (книжка "Вредные советы") :)

Answer (score 1):

Что произойдет, если пользователь отключит в браузере javascript? Он хоть что-нибудь сможет сделать на вашем сайте?

Вы должны создавать приложение, как если бы javascript полностью отключен, а затем на проект накручивать обработчики событий. Знайте, как бы ни проверялись данные в браузере пользователя, на сервере вы все равно должны полностью все перепроверить! Любой скрипт всегда можно обмануть. )))

Comment: Для отключенного JS есть страничка типа https://vk.com/badbrowser.php

В современном вебе без JS никуда, и не стОит отказываться от функционала только из-за того, что капризный пользователь отключил JS. Как говорят, назло маме уши отморожу. 

Единственное ограничение в верстке - это даже не ограничение, а доработка верстки таким образом, чтобы она сохраняла функциональность при отключеных картинках.

Помните, сколько геммороя принес фронтендам "шестой ослик". Убрали - но миллионных манифестаций нет, так же их не будет, если делать сайты только для браузеров, поддерживающих JS.

Comment: @dekameron, я не говорил, что нужно отказаться от js! Я говорю о том, что сайт не должен потерять функциональность даже при отключении скриптов. Здесь, на ХК я уже получил пинков за это. У меня тоже изаначально была авторизация через ajax. Получается, что пользователь без js вообще не мог зайти на сайт! Делайте стандартные submit для форм! А затем прикручивайте обработчики типа 

$(function(){ $('input[type=submit]').click(f)});

Тогда сайт будет работать в любом случае!

Comment: @Deus, да никто никому ничего не должен. Взвешиваете за и против для конкретно вашего сайта и решаете - дублировать ли функционал ради тех нескольких процентов людей без JS.

Comment: @xEdelweiss, ТС задал глупейший вопрос, типа, зачем капча, если все и так обрабатывается в браузере и ajax'ом передается на сервер. А вы своими идеями вносите недоразумение в мышление программистов-новичков. Еще вы пишете: "да никто никому ничего не должен", я и не говорил, что кто-то что-то должен. Я говорил "САЙТ" не должен. Хотя, может ТС просто делает морской бой... или косынку...

Comment: @xEdelweiss а учитывая, то js отключают обычно те, кого хоть немного беспокоят проблемы безопасности, то их отсев вполне разумен для сайтов-лохотронов...

Comment: @Deus ага вы не пишите

= Вы должны создавать приложение, как если бы javascript полностью отключен

Вообще сейчас это довольно бредово звучит. Если пользователь не может зайти на сайт, отключив у себя js, то это проблемы пользователя.

Comment: @rasmisha, ну да, а потом куча соплей: уважаемые, программисты, мой сайт вчера заспамили или взломали, ПОМОГИИИИТЕ!

Comment: @Deus сейчас я не про капчу, а обязательную поддержку юзеров без js.

Comment: @rasmisha, тогда странно, может вы просто не на тот вопрос пишете комментарии? )))

Comment: @Deus я на ваш бред по поводу "Вы должны создавать приложение, как если бы javascript полностью отключен"

Comment: @Deus, единственная относительно здравая мысль по вопросу у вас была 

> на сервере вы все равно должны
> полностью все перепроверить! Любой
> скрипт всегда можно обмануть.

Но как это вяжется с включенным/отключенным JS'ом? А поддержку допотопных браузеров вы тоже всем советуете направо и налево?

*И что значит "сайт" не должен? Он сам по себе фичами не обрастает.*

@alexlz, а если не учесть?

Comment: @Deus, Мне почему-то вспомнился ***тот самый*** вопрос про капчу)

Answer (score 0):

Когда Я добавлял на свой сайт форму обратной связи, Я не использовал капчу. Спама нет)

Comment: @nolka, а у вас хоть посетители есть? ))

Дайте ссылку на ваш сайт. Я не такой уж и  хакер, а вот местные хэш-кодовцы быстренько это все дело проверят

Comment: Сайт пока отключен за неуплату xD

Comment: @nolka, посоветуешь хороший хостинг? Без лимита процессорного времени и других неинтересных вещей?

Comment: насчет всех тонкостей не расскажу, доволен http://www.hetzner.co.za/

Comment: "Сайт пока отключен за неуплату" -- почему же интересно там нет спама?

Comment: @dzhioev, отличить бота от не бота можно не только при помощи капчи. Для обхода капчи существует сервисы типа antigate.com.

Капча - это не панацея.

@Deus budgetvm.com, digitalocean.com, clodo.ru. Я остановился на первом. Прельщает то, что оно находится далеко-далеко за горизонтом)